# Merge Table Rows Data in Mysql query based on date and one other field. Table have more than 2M rows

Tags: php, mysql, date, optimization

Here is sample table of data

```
  ID MC BC  TIME                  AB   AT 
   1  4  10  2016-12-05 09:02:00   5    8
   2  4  20  2016-12-15 09:03:00   2    3
   3  4  10  2016-12-15 09:02:00   1    4
   4  4  20  2016-12-25 09:02:00   3    6
   5  4  05  2016-12-05 09:02:00   4    2
   6  4  05  2016-12-08 09:02:00   6    2
   7  4  10  2016-12-11 09:02:00   7    6
   8  4  10  2016-12-05 09:02:00   9    8
   9  4  10  2016-12-15 09:02:00   9    8
  10  4  10  2016-12-15 09:05:00   10   20
  11  5  10  2016-12-15 09:05:00   10   20
  12  5  10  2016-12-15 09:05:00   10   20
  13  5  10  2016-12-15 09:05:00   10   20
```

If i query for where 'MC'= 4 and 'TIME' like `2016-12%` then i want data of 'AB' and 'AT' column merged based on day in 'TIME' column  and each 'BC' have separate day merged.

Like in sample output day 15 have two 'BC' (10,20) and they have two different rows.

I want the output like this

```
  ID  MC BC  TIME          AB   AT 
   1  4  10  2016-12-05    14   16
   2  4  10  2016-12-11     7    6
   3  4  10  2016-12-15    20   32
   4  4  20  2016-12-15     2    3
   5  4  20  2016-12-25     3    6
   6  4  05  2016-12-05     4    2
   7  4  05  2016-12-08     6    2
```

Table have more 2 million rows for current month like in sample table.

Comment: How AB & AT  calculated ? In short show us the formula you are using to calculate, your question is unclear to me

Comment: Thanks rahul_m for quick response. For AB and AT calculation  we added the AB value of one row with other rows which have same 'BC' and same day in 'TIME'. Like in first  row of output  data  we added the 'AB' of  first and eigth row of Sample Table. because they have same day 05 in 'TIME'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MC,
       BC,
       DATE(`TIME`) AS 'Day'
       SUM(AB) AS AB,
       SUM(AT) AS AT
    FROM tbl
    WHERE `TIME` >= '2016-12-01`
      AND `TIME`  < '2016-12-01` + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND MC = 4
    GROUP BY MC, BC, DATE(`TIME`);
```

This would be useful:

```
INDEX(MC, `TIME`)
```

Comment: Thanks Rick James  it working for me  and i'm really thankful to you.